# Opening raw resource with Robolectric test

Tags: android, android-resources, robolectric

I have a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper that opens an xml file to populate a SQLite database.  I am working on creating unit tests for it, but am stuck where I need to open the xml input resource:

```
context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.sample_input);
```

Debugging it, I can see that context.getResources() is non-null and is a shadow object, but the context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.sample_input) returns a null.

Reading around I see people mentioning that I need to create a shadow resource, but I don't see anywhere explaining how to do that for a case like this.

If it helps here's what my custom test runner class looks like currently

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass, new File("src/main/android/"));
    }
}
```

What am I missing to make resources work in my test?

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I figure this out I will come back with an answer.